# The X in the hat

Tags: american-english, prepositions

English is not my native language so I have gone through the pain of learning the difference between *in*, *on*, and *at*. However, it is common in the U.S. to refer to someone wearing a hat as *X in the hat*. A notable example is the children's book *The Cat in the Hat* by *Dr. Seuss*.

Using the latter example, we know that the cat is not *inside* the hat but instead the hat is *on top* of the cat. Why is it acceptable to say *The Cat in the Hat*?

Why is the expression *X in the Hat* acceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wearing a piece of clothes can be expressed like this:

> He looked good in his trench coat.
>
> They debated about running [bare or in shoe](http://www.cnn.com/2010/HEALTH/02/12/barefoot.running/index.html)s.

So it does not really matter whether the whole body or just small parts of it are actually "in" the piece of clothing. Therefore it seems perfectly valid to say

> Cat in the Hat.

Comment: Yep. You can be in a hat, in your shoes, and even (depending on whom you ask) in earmuffs, in a scarf, in makeup, or even in sunglasses. It's one of the stranger uses of "in", perhaps, but at least in certain dialects it's remarkably consistent.

Comment: to me, it helps to mentally say "You look good in that makeup" to make it sound normal. hearing it more abstractly, like "Being in makeup makes me feel better" still sounds strange.